# Go interface inheritance

Tags: go, interface

I am new to Go and don't understand one thing. Let's take one code which works:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type User struct {
    Name  string
    Email string
}

type Admin struct {
    User
    Level string
}

type Notifier interface {
    notify()
}

func (u *User) notify() {
    fmt.Println("Notified", u.Name)
}

func SendNotification(notify Notifier) {
    notify.notify()
}

func main() {
    admin := Admin{
        User: User{
            Name:  "john smith",
            Email: "john@email.com",
        },
        Level: "super",
    }

    SendNotification(&admin)
    admin.User.notify()
    admin.notify()
}
```

Here function *SendNotification* recognises admin struct as *Notifier*, because admin struct has access to embedded user struct which implements the interface via pointer receiver. Ok.
Why then the code below doesn't work. Why *norgateMathError* needs to implement the interface and not use implementation from err **error** (for me it is the same situation):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type norgateMathError struct {
    lat  string
    long string
    err  error
}

// func (n norgateMathError) Error() string {
//  return fmt.Sprintf("a norgate math error occured: %v %v %v", n.lat, n.long, n.err)
// }

func main() {
    _, err := sqrt(-10.23)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}

func sqrt(f float64) (float64, error) {
    if f < 0 {
        nme := fmt.Errorf("norgate math redux: square root of negative number: %v", f)
        return 0, &norgateMathError{"50.2289 N", "99.4656 W", nme}
    }
    return 42, nil
}
.\custom_error.go:28:13: cannot use &norgateMathError{...} (type *norgateMathError) as type error in return argument:
        *norgateMathError does not implement error (missing Error method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case `User` is *embedded* inside `Admin`, thus `Admin` gain access to all methods defined on the `User` type.

In the second case, `norgateMathError` *has* a field `err` of type `Error`, thus do not automatically gain access to it's methods.

If you want `norgateMathError` to have an `Error()` method you have to define it manually

```
func (n norgateMathError) Error() string {
  return n.err.Error()
}
```

There is a different between embedding a field and just having a field. More information can be found in the [reference](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#embedding)

Comment: Take a close look at `User` in your first struct and then `err error` in your second struct. Embedding refers to when you include a data type in a struct *without* a field name.